# Simple Question About Percentiles

Tags: probability, statistics, percentile

> An automobile insurance company issues a one-year policy with a deductible
> of $500$. The probability is $0.8$ that the insured automobile has no accident and
> $0.0$ that the automobile has more than one accident. If there is an accident,
> the loss before application of the deductible is exponentially distributed with
> mean $3000$. Calculate the $95$th percentile of the insurance company payout on this policy.

I found a solution online which begins with:

> The $95$th percentile is in the range when an accident occurs. It is the 75th percentile of the payout,
> given that an accident occurs, because $(0.95 − 0.80)/(1 − 0.80) = 0.75$.

Can someone please explain what the author of the solution was trying to achieve by writing $0.95-0.80$. I think $(1-0.80)$ is the probability that an accident occurs.

Comment: Roughly speaking, there is an 80 percent chance of no accident (and therefore no cost), and a 20 percent chance of exactly one accident.  Therefore, the 95th percentile of cost overall is 15 percent into that last 20 percent.  The cost distribution over that last 20 percent is essentially the cost of a single accident, "squeezed" into that last 20 percent.  So we're looking for the 75th percentile cost of a single accident, since 15 is 75 percent of the way through 20.